Confusion about how price of a contingent claim at time 1 could give arbitrage
I have been reading the book Tomas Bjork's Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time and could not understand how there could be arbitrage if the price of a contingent claim is not $X$.

To give some context, $X$ represents a European call option and $Z$ is a random variable representing how to stock will move at time 1. So if the stock price is $S$ at $t=0$, the stock price at $t=1$ can be written as $sZ$ where $Z=u$ would be the stock moving up and $Z=d$ would be the stock moving down.
I would like to figure it out myself so maybe just a hint on how this could be would be very helpful.

You mean the final question “(why?)” in the text?

Yes, I am sorry if it wasn’t clear.

Recall what $X$ is -- it is the value of the contingent claim at time $t = 1$. Now think how this relates to $\Pi(1; X)$.

I am going to assume that I can breakdown $t=1$ into two further time instants which I will confusingly call, $t=0$ and $t=1$, where $t=0$ is the time just before maturity. Assume that $\Pi(1:X)<X$, then at $t=0$, with stock price $S$ I will short $\Pi(1;X)/S$ number of stocks and buy an option at $\Pi(1;X)$. The initial value of this portfolio is zero. Now at maturity $t=1$, the option will be exercised so it is now worth $X$ and the portfolio is now $X-\Pi(1;X)>0$. So we have an arbitrage opportunity.

I think it’s simpler than you’re imagining. At $t=1$ the payout is fully determined, so the price of the claim must equal that payout. A concrete example might help. If a call option expires $10 in the money, the price of that contract at expiration must be $10. Otherwise there is an obvious arbitrage, ie. buy the contract if the price is less than $10 and sell if it is more than $10

I might have convoluted it but would you say buying the contract is the same as the situation I mentioned above?

I don't think you have it quite right. This is a one-period discrete time model, so there is no "time just before maturity". Also, you say "the option will be exercised" but this is not always true. Let me try again. At $t = 1$ we can directly observe the stock price so we know if $Z = u$ or $Z = d$. If $Z = u$ then owning the contingent claim will result in a risk-less positive cash inflow of $su - K$. If it costs less than $su - K$ to purchase the contingent claim, there is an obvious arbitrage opportunity (purchase the contingent claim for an immediate profit). I leave $Z = d$ for you.

By owning do you meaning buying the contingent claim at $t=1$? Also, if we don't exercise the option how would we have the cash inflow of $su-K$? But looking back, I really did not mention that $S=us$ so there would be a possibly of the option not being exercised, I think?

In the case I treated, when $Z = u$, you would indeed exercise the option. But when $Z = d$ you would not exercise the option. I am trying to say that at $t = 1$ the payoff of the contingent claim is known and riskless, so if you can pay less than $su - K$ for something that pays you $su - K$ you certainly will. The arbitrage is right there; paying 9 for something that immediately gives you 10.

I think I understand now. So for $Z=d$, $X=0$ but if the price is greater than zero (which I think is the only possibility) and I have the option, I would just sell it?

Yep! Even if you don't have the option, you would short as many as you could.

Thank you so much for your time! I feel like I understand things better!
